# How do I randomly pick an element in each column of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random

Question title explains what I would like. For example, if there are 6 elements in a particular column, how do I randomly pick 1 element from that column. Please keep it simple if possible.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a matrix `A` of size `m`-by-`n`. You wish to pick one element from each of the `n` columns at random:

```
>> rows = randsample( m, n ); % sample n times from integers 1:m
```

Now `rows` has `n` values, each represent a random entry at the corresponding column.
To access those values

```
>> sampledValues = A( sub2ind( size(A), rows, 1:n ) );
```

For more information see the doc on [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `randi` if your version of MATLAB is > R2008a

```
samples = A(sparse(randi(size(A,1),size(A,2),1), 1:size(A,2), true));
```

or,

```
[m, n] = size(A);
samples = A(sparse(randi(m,n,1), 1:n, true));
```

However for older versions you can replace `randi` with `randsample` but that requires Statistics Toolbox. Or introduce:

```
randi = @(imax, m, n) floor(1+rand(m,n)*imax);
```

Comment: I guess `floor(1+rand(m,n)*imax)` can be slightly simplified to `ceil(rand(m,n)*imax)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it. Note that a version without loops should be more efficient.

Assuming your variable is `x` loop over its `n` columns:

```
selected = zeros(1,n);
for c = 1:n
    selected(c) =  x(randperm(6,1),n);
end
```